# AutoLayout Xcode. iPhone simulators don't match Xcode preview

Tags: ios, xcode, view, autolayout

Problem is :

I am setting my autolayout, and there are not any errors or warning :

[image]

I have the preview of main storyboard with 2 devices (Iphone 5, Iphone 6+)

And all views look good, but then I am trying to start the Iphone Simulator, it shows me this hell. Please, answer me. Why does it happen?

[image]

**P.S.** I am using this launch screen :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post a link to the project?  It's hard to tell what the issue is based on the screenshots alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure the constraint you set are on for screen size any and any
I can see compact and Regular in your screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

On the last screenshot there are two warnings, you should check them to see it they are related in any way.

[image]

Comment: I checked, These were not about layout. Now there are not any problems, but situation is the same. It's really strange, cause in previews - it's okay.